# date time picker failed to initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, zepto

I used this plugin https://github.com/trentrichardson/Intimidatetime and together with zepto (lightweight jquery alike library) but I got undefined is not a function error.

My demo is here : http://jsfiddle.net/zkLnpy4r/

The plugin doc says do like this

```
$(function($) {
    $('#pname').intimidatetime();
});
```

and I did but something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `intimidatetime css` and `jQuery` reference.

[**See updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zkLnpy4r/3/)